# Manager Hyper-V Server 2016 (core) with Windows 7 Pro + HyperV MNG

Tags: windows-7, hyper-v, hypervisor

I would like to know if it is possible to use Hyper-V Manager on Windows 7 Pro to manage Hyper-V 2016 server (core)? I installed Hyper-V Manager, made some configurations on the Windows 7 Pro, to release firewall, but I still could not connect. The error that occurs is that the RPC service failed. Attention: both are in domain, and I can connect to Hyper-V 2016 through to TS. Attention 2: I am not asking to run Hyper-V ON the Windows 7 Pro, it is to MANAGER (through my lan) my Hyper-V servers.

Comment: It is not.  Or at least not via the GUI,

Comment: Could you explain more, why not?

Comment: That is the way Microsoft made it.

Answer (score 0):

Hyper-V Manager in Windows 7 only speaks version 1 of the Hyper-V API. Hyper-V Server 2016 only speaks version 2 of the API. Only Windows 10, with Hyper-V Manager, will fully manage it.